# В чем принципиальный смысл двоеточия при отделение блоков кода в Python?

Tags: python, интерпретатор, отступы, dry

Есть принцип DRY, то есть "не повторяйся". Когда мы пишем функцию def, используем if, for и другие инструкции, то в конце ставим двоеточие для отделения блока кода от его объявления. А на следующей строке обязательно используем отступ в 4 пробела с той же целью. Разве это не нарушение DRY? В чем тогда сакральный смысл двоеточия? Оно под капотом Python как-то обрабатывается? Разве одной табуляции было бы не достаточно?

Может вопрос и странный, но я не могу представить себе ситуацию, в которой отсутствие двоеточия сломало бы код. Если задача только визуально отделить необходимый блок кода, то с этим справляется табуляция. Поэтому есть ощущение, что я не до конца понимаю сам смысл двоеточия с точки зрения обработки кода интерпретатором

с точки зрения синтаксиса двоеточие и отступ выполняют одно у ту же функцию - отделение вложенного блока кода.

Comment: Есть такое понятие как синтаксис. С такой же логикой Вы могли задаться вопросом "Зачем делать отступы? - Это же повторение пробелов!!!"

Comment: вы не поняли видимо. с точки зрения синтаксиса двоеточие и отступ выполняют одно у ту же функцию - отделение вложенного блока кода. зачем такое дублирование?  4 пробела в начале строки и отступ это одно и тоже, а не разные элементы синтаксиса, так что ваш пример не по теме

Comment: Вот документация по этому поводу https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html

Comment: "Составной оператор состоит из одного или нескольких «предложений». Предложение состоит из заголовка и «набора». Заголовки предложений конкретного составного оператора находятся на одном уровне отступа. Заголовок каждого предложения начинается с уникального ключевого слова и заканчивается двоеточием"

Comment: как минимум нужно для `lambda`

Comment: @Danis `lambda` пишется в одну строку всегда. речь не о двоеточии как таковом, а о случаях отделения вложенного блока кода, например в `if` или `for`. у `lambda` такого задвоения функционала нет

Comment: @СергейКох спасибо за ссылку, почитаю, но пока я увидел только описание, что двоеточие нужно ставить, но не увидел какой в этом принципиальный смысл. в крайнем случае его можно было бы оставить для тех, кто любит длинный код в одну строчку писать. или можно использовать тогда запятую, ведь её нельзя использовать при проверке условий, разделение было бы очевидно. так даже было бы логичнее кстати. но зачем двоеточие в традиционном многострочном стиле кода с отступами? я думал его интерпретатор как-то обрабатывает под капотом, но, судя по ответам, ничего подобного не происходит

Comment: нашёл на английском версии сайта такой же вопрос: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215581/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-before-a-block-in-python но внем сказано примерно тоже самое

Comment: да, я уже тоже нашел, спасибо комментарию @Эникейщик. Гвидо видимо задолбали этим вопросом, поэтому "it's too late to change". кстати ещё он [**писал**](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2009/02/early-language-design-and-development.html), что так новички лучше учатся, делают меньше ошибок. в принципе тоже аргумент

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Обратимся к автору](https://markmail.org/message/ve7mwqxhci4pm6lw): двоеточие нужно для улучшения читаемости. Технической необходимости в этом действительно нет.

> The colon is required primarily to enhance readability (one of the results of the experimental ABC language). Consider this:
>
> ```
> if a == b 
>     print a
> ```
>
> versus
>
> ```
> if a == b: 
>     print a
> ```
>
> Notice how the second one is slightly easier to read. Notice further how a colon sets off the example in the second line of this FAQ answer; it's a standard usage in English. Finally, the colon makes it easier for editors with syntax highlighting.

Comment: Спасибо, видимо на этом можно остановиться. помимо [этого обсуждения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215581/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-colon-before-a-block-in-python) и [этого ответа Гвидо](https://markmail.org/message/ve7mwqxhci4pm6lw), с комментарием "but anyway, it's too late to change", нашел его статью, в которой сказано, что [новички так лучше учатся](http://python-history.blogspot.com/2009/02/early-language-design-and-development.html). всё еще считаю, что лично мне без `:` было бы удобнее и нарушается принцип [TOOWTDI](https://peps.python.org/pep-0020/), но в целом аргументы понял

Answer (score 6):

Хорошо, давайте попробуем сократить одну из "лишних" сущностей.

- Начнём с отступа

```
def func():
print('Hello world!')
a = 1
b = 2
c = a + b
print(c)
func()
```

Так, стоп - а как понять, что функция кончилась? Придётся ещё какое-то правило вводить, например, пустую строку в конце функции.

```
def func():
print('Hello world!')
a = 1
b = 2
c = a + b
print(c)

func()
```

Хм, ну это вариант, но лучше ли это, чем отступы, нагляднее ли? А если добавить ещё таких же сущностей внутрь функции.

```
def func():
print('Hello world!')
a = 1
b = 2
if a > b:
c = a - b
else:
c = a + b
print(c)

func()
```

Так, стоп, а как понять, где кончились строки внутри блоков `if`?! И так, чтобы не перепутать их с концом функции? Тоже с помощью пустой строки? Ну ладно, добавим ещё после `else:` пустую строку.

```
def func():
print('Hello world!')
a = 1
b = 2
if a > b:
c = a - b
else:
c = a + b

print(c)

func()
```

Понятно ли в таком виде, где кончился `else:`, а где `def`? А если это длинная функция и там ещё есть внутри уровни вложенности? Это тогда придётся считать пустые строки, чтобы понять, конец какого блока эта пустая строка означает? И считать потом назад конструкции, начинающие блоки. Кажется, код постепенно становится не читаемым. :/

- Теперь попробуем оставить отступы, но не двоеточие

```
def func()
    print('Hello world!')
    a = 1
    b = 2
    if a > b
        c = a - b
    else
        c = a + b
    print(c)

func()
```

Выглядит неплохо (хотя и не так чётко как с двоеточием), но возникают проблемы с тем, что мы уже не можем написать в одну строчку код, так, чтобы было всё чётко отделено.

```
if a > b c = a - b
```

Вы сможете сходу понять глядя на такой код где кончилось условие и где начался код внутри уже блока `if`? И сразу понять, глядя на этот код, нет ли тут каких ошибок? Я вот что-то уже не уверен. Если только запретить продолжать код в той же строке, тогда ещё ладно. Но всё-равно не будет чёткого видения, где же тут кончился оператор и начался блок внутри оператора.

Подозреваю, что вылезут и ещё какие-то проблемы, но сходу пока больше не придумал.

В целом мне лично кажется удобным иметь простое правило: видишь в конце строки двоеточие - значит дальше должны быть строки с отступом. Это позволяет быстро глазами увидеть, правильно ли сделаны отступы в программе.

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ, но важность отступов я под сомнение не ставил, первые примеры лишние. последний уже в тему, но да, могу сходу понять. в питоне стоит жесткий запрет на операции присваивания в if, так что в данном конкретном случае интерпретатор мог бы их различать. тем более после сравнения сразу идет операция присваивания, это еще один флаг чтобы их различить в автоматическом режиме - отсутствие `or`, `and` и прочих операторов. но в целом да - удобство написания в одну строку пока самый логичный вариант. но саму возможность этого по-моему и без двоеточия можно сохранить

Comment: @Jericho Ну мне из вопроса не очевидным показалось, что именно вам кажется излишним )

Comment: сама тема вопроса звучит "в чем смысл **двоеточия**" :) отступы действительно необходимы для отделения блоков кода, в каком-то роде мне из-за них и нравится питон. в глазах рябит от фигурных скобок. но их функционал во много уже включает в себя более скромный функционал двоеточия, вот и захотелось разобраться, может я что-то про него не знаю

Comment: @Jericho Да, я как-то шире на проблему посмотрел чёто )

Comment: кстати ваш пример с функцией, условием, отступами, но без двоеточия мне кажется симпатичнее общепринятого синтаксиса. я понимаю, что явное лучше неявного, но если бы было голосование за самый оптимальный вариант, то я бы за этот пример проголосовал ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Буря в стакане воды. А всего-то и надо было не выпендриваться, а изначально сделать фигурные скобочки (как во всех нормальных языках)

Comment: @avp это вкусовщина уже. для меня нормальный язык должен быть лаконичен, а в некоторых языках эти фигурные скобки пихают в каждую вторую строку. отступы наше всё :)

Comment: @avp Мне хватает холивара где именно эти скобочки ставить )))

Comment: @Jericho, не то чтобы я был сильно удивлен, но оказывается некоторые люди практически работают над использованием скобочек для форматирования кода -- [Denote Scopes with Braces

Easily my favorite advanced feature in Python, rather than relying on whitespace to denote scopes (boring) — we can use curly braces!](https://towardsdatascience.com/five-advanced-python-features-169c96682350)

Answer (score 3):

Двоеточие визуально разграничивают ключевые слова и код. До двоеточия ключевое слова, а далее код.

Внутри ключевых слов действуют некоторые ограничения, такие как запрет на написания нескольких строк, запрет на оператор присвоения, поэтому необходимо разделение.

А двоеточие, в отличие от отступа, делает это **явно**.
А как известно:

> Explicit is better than implicit.

Comment: именно об этом и вопрос. разве отступ в следующей строке не включает в себя всё, что вы описали? я понимаю зачем в принципе нужно двоеточие, вопрос в том, что если есть вложенный блок кода, то он и без двоеточия будет отделен отступом, то есть и так будет разграничение описанное вами. и получается нарушение принципа DRY

Comment: @Jericho двоеточие делает это гораздо более явно

Comment: видимо "явное лучше неявного" самый подходящий вариант. по крайней мере вариант "двоеточие выполняет функции под капотом питона" можно отсеять. но мое личное мнение тогда - в обычном многострочном коде с отступами это лишний символ, которые не вносит ничего, кроме потенциальных ошибок если его забыть. а в однострочном коде можно придумать решения и без двоеточия. ну или в крайнем случае оставить его специально для таких случаев. 
спасибо за ответы :)

Comment: "There should be one – and preferably only one – obvious way to do it" кстати тоже оттуда. ну да ладно, может у меня голландские корни где-то есть)

Answer (score 0):

Возможно не совсем ответ на вопрос. Но двоеточие - это признак, что на следующей строке должен быть добавлен отступ.

Comment: Но допустимо и так `if x == 4: print(x, y)`

Comment: если написать def func() и нажать enter, то отступ вставится автоматически и без двоеточия. по крайней мере в PyCharm. сначала подумал, что вы правы, но, видимо, Python это понимает сам. это не является признаком для отступа

Comment: А вот, кстати, это, возможно, и есть причина добавления двоеточия.

Comment: @СергейКох пока это самый логичный вариант. но такое написание кода не считается корректным, в реальной программе за такое не похвалят мне кажется. это скорее использование недокументированной возможности. да и Python сам мог бы определять когда заканчиваются проверки условий, аргументы функции или аннотации, а когда идет блок следующего кода. то есть если убрать двоеточие, то можно было бы сохранить функционал и в вашем примере. тем более обычно это используется только когда в конце идет `pass`. но в целом пока это лучший вариант, с ним можно придумать пример когда код перестанет работать

Comment: @Jericho https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#other-recommendations:~:text=0%2C%20)-,Immediately%20before,-a%20comma%2C%20semicolon

Comment: @СергейКох это пример того, что перед двоеточием не надо ставить пробелы. не совсем то. объяснения зачем в принципе двоеточие нужно там нет. тем более там в строчку просто перечислены 3 примера. очевидно для удобства просмотра небольших примеров, а не как рекомендация для реального применения такого стиля кода

Comment: Все признаки, когда наследующей строке нужен отступ и так известны и их не так уж и много - после определенных ключевых слов типа def, if, while, class и т.п. С технической точки зрения нет необходимости дублировать их еще и двоеточием.

Comment: @Эникейщик именно! не я один я так считаю, и то хорошо)

Comment: В Python IDLE если не поставить : после def func(), то написав def func() и нажав Enter отступ автоматически не вставится...

Comment: @AleksandrАZeD справедливости ради там много чего нет, она довольно ущербна. в PyCharm например такой проблемы нет, так что реализовать автоматические отступы не проблема